# PCA for high dimensional matrix

Tags: pca

I have 20 4D matrix and I want to perform PCA on them to get may be 2 or 3 4D matrix that explains most of the variance. I think this means I have 20 observations, but how do I organize my 20 observations into a matrix to perform PCA? Is it correct to just arrange each matrix into a column? I am unsure about it beacuse I feel though the 20 matrix are correlated, elements in the individual matrice are not.

Is there anyone here to help me understand PCA? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [Multilinear PCA](http://www.dsp.utoronto.ca/~haiping/Publication/MPCA_TNN08_rev2010.pdf) (a generalization of PCA to higher order tensors). A Matlab implementation can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26168-multilinear-principal-component-analysis--mpca-).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.